# Mongoose: what's up with "_doc"?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

It seems Mongoose is doing something really funky internally.

```
var Foo = new mongoose.model('Foo', new mongoose.Schema({a: String, b: Number}));
var foo = new Foo({a: 'test'; b: 42}); 
var obj = {c: 1};
foo.goo = obj;                  // simple object assignment. obj should be 
                                  //   passed by reference to foo.goo. recall goo
                                  //   is not defined in the Foo model schema

console.log(foo.goo === obj);   // comparison directly after the assignment
    // => false, doesn't behave like normal JS object
```

Essentially, any time you try to deal with properties of a Mongoose model that aren't

a) defined in the model's schema or

b) defined as the same type (array, obj, ..) ... the model doesn't even behave like a normal Javascript object.

Switching line **4** to `foo._doc.goo = obj` makes the console output `true`.

**edit**: trying to reproduce weirdness

**example 1**:

```
 // Customer has a property 'name', but no property 'text'
 // I do this because I need to transform my data slightly before sending it
 // to client.
 models.Customer.find({}, function(err, data) {
     for (var i=0, len=data.length; i<len; ++i) {
        data[i] = data[i]._doc;            // if I don't do this, returned data
                                           // has no 'text' property
        data[i].text = data[i].name;       
    }
    res.json({success: err, response:data});
});
```

Comment: `goo` is a string, yet you've put an object in the value?

Comment: @WiredPrairie I've re-written to better illustrate the weirdness

Comment: I can't replicate the problem you're having in the first example still. What version of NodeJS and mongo are you using?

Comment: Added a bit more detail about what's happening in the second example.

Comment: @Colin It looks like the answer doesn't really match your question anymore, did you ever figure out why ._doc exists / why the Document from Mongoose doesn't behave the way we expect javascript objects to?

Comment: you should try using the spread operator. So the response would be something along the lines on { ...response }

And you might need { ...{ ...response }._doc } to get to your original data

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Update

*Maybe I misunderstood your original question, but now it looks like the nature of your question changed, so the below information isn't relevant, but I'm leaving it. :)*

I tested your code and it works fine for me. Mongoose doesn't execute any special code when you set properties that aren't part of the schema (or a few other special properties). JavaScript currently doesn't support calling code for properties that don't yet exist (so Mongoose can't get in the way of the set of the `goo` property for example).

So, when you set the property:

```
foo.goo = { c: 1 };
```

Mongoose isn't involved. If your `console.log` was something other than the code you displayed, I could see that it might report incorrectly.

Additionally, when you `send` the results back as JSON, `JSON.stringify` is being called, which calls `toString` on your Mongoose Model. When that happens, Mongoose only uses the properties defined on the schema. So, no additional properties are being sent back by default. You've changed the nature of the `data` array though to directly point at the Mongoose data, so it avoids that problem.

#### Details about normal behavior

When you set the property `goo` using Mongoose, quite a few things happen. Mongoose creates property getters/setters via the `Object.defineProperty` (some [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)). So, when you set the `goo` property, which you've defined as a `[String]`, a few things happen:

1. Mongoose code is called prior to the value being set onto the object instance (unlike a simple JavaScript object)
2. Mongoose creates an array (optionally) to store the data (a `MongooseArray`) which will contain the array data. In the example you provided, since you didn't pass an array, it will be created.
3. Mongoose will attempt to cast your data to the right type
4. It will call `toString` on the data passed as part of the cast.

So, the results are that the document now contains an array with a `toString` version of the object you passed.

If you checked the contents of the `goo` property, you'd see that it's now an array with a single element, which is a string that contains `[object Object]`. If you'd picked a more basic type or matched the destination property storage type, you would see that a basic equality check would have worked.

Comment: Sorry, I think I edited the question whilst you were responding :S

Comment: Yes, you did. :)  I edited the answer to reflect your new changes.

Comment: Ah yes. I see clearly now.. the rain is gone. Thanks for all your help man; much appreciated!

Answer (score 13):

**_doc** exist on the mongoose object.

Because **mongooseModel.findOne** returns the model itself, the model has structure (protected fields).
When you try to print the object with console.log it gives you only the data from the database, because console.log will print the object public fields.

If you try something like JSON.stringify then you get to see inside the mongoose model object. (_doc, state ...)

In the case where you want to add more fields in the object and it's not working

```
const car = model.findOne({_id:'1'})
car.someNewProp = true // this will not work
```

If later you set the property to the object car and you didn't specify in the Model Schema before then Mongoose model is validating if this field exists and if it's the valid type. 
If the validation fails then the property will not be set.

Comment: great explanation bro. This is exactly what i was will know. Thank you so much

Comment: Great explanation. Can you direct me towards some documentation of `_doc` since I couldn't find it at mongoose docs myself. Thanks.

Comment: Can you simplify the answer - what exactly is the meaning of "protected fields", "public fields", "only from database"?

Answer (score 8):

you can use toJSON() instead of _doc

Comment: Can you provide supporting documentation for further understanding?

Answer (score 4):

You should add [`.lean()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html#using-lean) on the find to have it skip all the Model 'magic.'

Comment: This should be at the top

Answer (score 3):

Had same problem. Instead of updating my model.

```
const car = model.findOne({_id:'1'})
let temp = JSON.stringify(car);
let objCar = JSON.parse(temp);
objCar.color = 'Red'; //now add any property you want
```

this solves my problem

Answer (score 3):

Try using lean

> By default, Mongoose queries return an instance of the Mongoose Document class. Documents are much heavier than vanilla JavaScript objects, because they have a lot of internal state for change tracking. Enabling the lean option tells Mongoose to skip instantiating a full Mongoose document and just give you the POJO.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck on this today... Drove me nuts. Not sure if the below is a good solution (and OP has mentioned it too), but this is how I overcame this issue.

My car object:

```
 cars = [{"make" : "Toyota"}, {"make" : "Kia"}];
```

Action:

```
console.log("1. Cars before the color: " + car);

cars.forEach(function(car){
     car.colour = "Black";   //color is NOT defined in the model. 
});

console.log("2. Cars after the color: " + car);
```

Problematic console output:

```
   1. Cars before the color: [{"make" : "Toyota"}, {"make" : "Kia"}];
   2. Cars after the color: [{"make" : "Toyota"}, {"make" : "Kia"}];   //No change! No new colour properties :(
```

If you try to pass in this property that was undefined in the model, via doc (e.g. car.**_doc**.color = "black"), it will work (this colour property will be assigned to each car), but **you can't seem to access it via EJS (frontend)** for some reason.

**Solution**:
(Again, not sure if this is the best way... but it worked for me): Add in this new property (colour) in the car model.

```
var carSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   make: String,
   color: String   //New property.
})
```

With the model redefined, everything worked as normal / expected (no _doc 'hacks' needed etc.) and I lived another day; hope it helps someone else.

Comment: Here I answered your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60978177/1566628

Answer (score 1):

For those using spread(...) and/ can't see a solution, here's an example of @entesar's answer

Instead of spread or ._doc in:

```
import User from "./models/user";

...
async function createUser(req, res) {
  const user = await User.create(req.body);


  res.status(201).json({
    message: "user created",
    data: {
        ...user // OR user._doc,
        token: "xxxxxxxx",
     },
   });
}
...
```

Use this

```
import User from "./models/user";

...
async function createUser(req, res) {
  const user = await User.create(req.body);


  res.status(201).json({
    message: "user created",
    data: {
        ...user.toJSON(),
        token: "xxxxxxxx",
     },
   });
}
...
```

Ps: took me a while to understand the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is some weirdness with Mongoose models and you have to check that Mongoose doesn't already have a model created in it's models array.

Here is my solution:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
createModel = (modelName="foo", schemaDef, schemaOptions = {})=> {
  const { Schema } = mongoose;
  const schema = Schema(schemaDef, schemaOptions);
  const Model = mongoose.models[modelName] || mongoose.model(modelName, schema);
  return Model;
}
```

I use my own mongoose model class and base class for my models. I made this and it  should work for you.