# Failing to add a key and value to a javascript object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to JavaScript and Node etc but enjoying the experience of developing - last serious development i did was in the 90s - I used to be a 370 assembler programmer back 30 years ago!

I've been stuck on this all day.

My issue is that I am trying to add a new element to the entries in an array of objects.  I have simplified my code here in the hope that I am doing something blindingly stupid and obviously wrong though I have tried this in javascript in the browser and I know I am barking up the right tree.

What I am trying to do is add a new key/value pair to the collectibles returned. I have simplified the code here but in essence the value is coming for a different collection.  the issue is that the lines that set the new keys are having no effect on my objects in the array collectibles.  I have tried several methods all of which I believe should work.

I can read the key/values in the returned array of objects and I can also set existing keys to new values, but setting a new key is not working.

Here is my code:

```
var sendJsonResponse = function (res, status, content) {
    res.status(status);
    res.json(content);
};

var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Coll = mongoose.model("collectible");
var Img = mongoose.model("image");


module.exports.collectiblesList = function (req, res) {
    var firstImage_ids = [];
    var imageDir = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxxxxxx/images/";
    var defaultImage = imageDir + "default.jpg";


    // get the collectibles
    Coll.find(req.body).exec(function (err, collectibles) {
        if (!collectibles) {
            // not found
            sendJsonResponse(res, 404, {"message": "no collectibles found"});
            return;
        }
        if (err) {
            console.log(collectible);
            sendJsonResponse(res, 400, err);
            return;
        }
        //found the collectibles
        // now find the list of images we need to pull (each collectible can have multiple images
        collectibles.forEach(function (collectible, index) {
            if (collectible.image_ids) {
                firstImage_ids.push(collectible.image_ids[0]);
                collectibles[index].imageUrl = defaultImage;    // this is the line that has no effect.
                collectible.imageUrl = defaultImage;        // tried this too.
                collectible["imageUrl"] = defaultImage;         // and this. :-(
                console.log(collectible);
            }
        });
        sendJsonResponse(res, 200, collectibles);
    });
};
```

Using Postman to test this API.  This is what is being returned:

```
[
{
    "_id": "5a43c61134aaea2025158cab",
    "name": "A-0_5",
    "title": "Occoneechee Lodge 104: A-0_5",
    "issueDate": null,
    "quantity": null,
    "event_id": null,
    "type": "A - Arrowhead patches",
    "tag_ids": [
        "5a401a17b720186ab61c649e"
    ],
    "description": "Elangomat, no name",
    "organisation_id": "5a413340b720186ab61c661e",
    "supercedes_id": null,
    "sortName": "A-000.5",
    "image_ids": [
        "5a41685ab720186ab61c663d"
    ],
    "deleted": false,
    "schemaVersion": "1.0"
},
{
    "_id": "5a43c63334aaea2025158cac",
    "name": "A-1",
    "title": "Occoneechee Lodge 104: A-1",
    "issueDate": null,
    "quantity": null,
    "event_id": null,
    "type": "A - Arrowhead patches",
    "tag_ids": [
        "5a401a17b720186ab61c649e"
    ],
    "description": "Service",
    "organisation_id": "5a413340b720186ab61c661e",
    "supercedes_id": null,
    "sortName": "A-001",
    "image_ids": [
        "5a41685ab720186ab61c663e"
    ],
    "deleted": false,
    "schemaVersion": "1.0"
}]
```

i.e. it contains no imageUrl keys.

thanks for the assist.

WWW
GT

Comment: I can't exactly say off hand why this isn't working, but I think it might have something to do with modifying the mongoose response.  You might try an immutable approach using collectibles.map(...) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I might have misunderstood. But if your issue is that collectibles[i].imageUrl is later on returning undefined/null, then i believe it's simply because you need to add

```
collectibles.save();
```

after setting the collectibles[i].imageUrl value. you can add that line after the foreach loop, before the json response.

```
collectibles.forEach(function (collectible, index) {
    if (collectible.image_ids) {
        firstImage_ids.push(collectible.image_ids[0]);
        collectible.imageUrl = defaultImage;
    }
});
collectibles.save(); //here, this saves the changes done to the mongoose object.
sendJsonResponse(res, 200, collectibles);
```

Comment: I am not planning on updating the data in mongoDB, just add the ImageURLs to the collectibles that are returned thru a RESTful API.  mongoose.save() .  I assume that is what the collectible.save() does?

Comment: oh, so the value isn't being changed in the first place ? in that case, start with making sure the if (collectible.image_ids) statement is being passed in the first place by a adding a console.log inside it before any other code. if the if statement is indeed passed. then your issue is the collectible object itself. Is it possible you have not defined the property imageUrl in your collectible schema ? because to my knowledge, mongoose doesn't allow the addition of unknown properties - ones not defined in the schema

Comment: I worked it out - it took a lot of effort and I came up with two ways to solve it.  The object I am adding to is not all it appears to be.  This article explains (but i dont fully yet follow the explaination)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18821212/mongoose-whats-up-with-doc

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in the end after a lot of effort.  [This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18821212/mongoose-whats-up-with-doc) explains (but i don't fully yet follow the explanation)

I found that the object has more metadata in it and the actual object is in _doc, so the first (and i suspect frowned upon solution) is to update the code to:

collectible._doc.imageUrl = defaultImage;

The better way was to simply add imageUrl to the mongoose model and leave _doc out of it.  The issue there is that this is not a field i intend to populate in the mongoDB.