# Mongoose ORM - find query returns the document wrapped in _doc object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am facing a weird situation with Mongoose on my current project I am working on. On my User collection, a find query such as this `user.findOne({email: req.body.email)` used to return me the mongoose object with the user information such as `{name: "", attn: "", visited: ""}` with no problem.

Lately, I have decided to rewrite the project, using the same Node.js, Mongoose, and Express version, with the same mongoose models and such. Now, the same find query returns me the user object but wrapper within a `_doc` mongoose object.

I have looked around and I can't find the problem. Does anyone experiences the same issues? Any tip or help?

What is even weird, I have returned and downloaded the old project on github and it's also returning the wrapped mongoose `_doc` object on a find query.

Any help will be greatly appreciated as I have looked around and couldn't find any concrete solution to this.

```
Node -v 11.2.0
Mongoose -v 5.7.6
```

More code for clarity below.

Like this query below used to return the mongoose model i.e

```
let user = await UserModel.findOne({email: req.body.email})
console.log(user) ==> {name: 'Alex', attn: 'sir', address: '57445'}
```

Now for some reasons the same query would return like this below

```
console.log(user) ==> model {$__: InternalCache, isNew: false, errors: undefined, $locals: {…}, $op: null, _doc: {name: 'Alex', attn:'Sir', address: '57445}}
```

Any help solving this?

Comment: This may be able to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18821212/mongoose-whats-up-with-doc

Comment: Can you provide an example of the code where you are exposing `_doc`? That's the internal store for the data in a `Document` object

Comment: @TonyDrummond Thank you for the link you provide, but it does not quite address the situation I am experiencing. As I was saying above, I used to retrieve the full mongoose document after a query without problem. Now it seems that the model is wrapped inside a _doc object and I am not sure why or how to fix it

Comment: @Matt Hi Matt, please find my edit above, I have provided a piece of code that illustrates the issue I am running into, any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I doubt the query is returning anything different. `console.log()` would normally call `user.toObject()` to get the first output. The second is just displaying the underlying `user` object. Not sure, try with an even Node and 5.10 mongoose?

Comment: @Matt I can't directly access a user field like before. Something like user.name returns undefined I have to do user._doc.name now. I am going to update mongoose and node and report any findings.

Comment: @Matt I have tried everything, downgraded Node.js, mongoose, mongodb but I am still having the same issue. It's weird that boolean field can't be accessed directly on the modele as I am receiving 'undefined' values, but within the user._doc I can access them. I really don't know If I should refactor my code and continue accessing model fields within the _doc object. Any help

Comment: Don't use `_doc` directly, if you don't have the virtual accessors on the returned document then something is wrong.  What happens when you call `user.toObject()`?

Comment: or create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update the code with that, or create an issue on github